# Not able to attach database backup file .bak into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database backup file named `iyym.bak`. How can I attach the database to my SQL Server 2008?

I tried inside SQL Server Management Studio the following:

- right click on data base folder in object explorer
- selected attach
- click add button.

When I am trying to add the backup error showing `iyym.bak` is not a primary database.

I have used the same version of SQL Server to take the backup too.

How can I attach this back?

Comment: I think this should probably be better on dba.stackexchange.com.  I think you need to 'restore' this rather than attach it however.

Answer (score 2):

A .bak file isn't supposed to be ATTACHED.  It's a backup file that you RESTORE.

Try something like the following:

`RESTORE DATABASE [DbNameGoesHere] FROM DISK ='C:\PathtoBackup\Backup.bak'`

Here's the MSDN article that has all the switches and arguments:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

You cannot Attach an SQL Server Backup File.

Instead, you need to create a new empty database, and them restore the backup on top of it. Just make sure to replace the MDF and LDF Path a file name to match your new DB files, and to check the option WITH_Replace.